# How to find vendor name from JEDEC id?

Tags: hardware-id

I would like to get the manufacturer name from JEDEC ids. Here is an example of some ids.

```
JEDEC ID:7F 7F 7F 7F 7F 51 00 00
JEDEC ID:80 2C
JEDEC ID:80 CE
JEDEC ID:AD 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
JEDEC ID:CE 01 09 13 45 67 5E F4
JEDEC ID:CE 01 09 13 47 7A 3E 5A
```

I found this [list](http://www.idhw.com/textual/chip/jedec_spd_man.html) of manufacturer ids from JEDEC, but I’m not sure if this ids match to my ids and how to connect them correctly.

For example:

If I look at the JEDEC id `CE 01 09 13 47 7A 3E 5A`, the first Byte `CE` is equal to `11001110`. If I compare this value with the JEDEC [list](http://www.idhw.com/textual/chip/jedec_spd_man.html), I get Samsung as Vendor. This is correct for the hardware.

But for example the Byte value `80` from JEDEC id `80 CE` is missing in the [list](http://www.idhw.com/textual/chip/jedec_spd_man.html). Also I cannot find the vendor for `7F 7F 7F 7F 7F 51 00 00`. Additional to that I don’t know when to use which Byte value from the JEDEC [list](http://www.idhw.com/textual/chip/jedec_spd_man.html) (Byte 1, Byte 2, ...) In guess `01 00 00 00` is *AMD* and `00 00 01 00` is *Camintonn Corporation*. But in my case I haven’t any leading zeros. How should I know when to use the second Byte value?

Any idea how to get the vendor name from the ids? Are there any rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JEDEC provides a document called JEP106 which contains all manufacturers. You can download this document [here](http://www.jedec.org/standards-documents/results/JEP106) (rev AP release in Feb 2015). In that document the different banks are continued with the byte value `7F`.

If you have the id `7F 01` you’re in the second bank and you’re vendor is *Cirrus Logic*. Without leading `7F` you’re in the first bank.